# How to create database by Ansible with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ansible

Use this task to create a database on CentOS by Ansible

```
- name: Create mydb database
  command: createdb -E UNICODE -l en_US.UTF-8 -T template0 mydb -O mydbuser
  become_user: postgres
```

It will pending. Output:

```
TASK [db_primary : Create mydb database] *********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [stg-master]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["createdb", "-E", "UNICODE", "-l", "en_US.UTF-8", "-T", "template0", "mydb", "-O", "mydbuser"], "delta": "0:00:44.323037", "end": "2020-09-17 18:44:48.873994", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-09-17 18:44:04.550957", "stderr": "WARNING:  canceling the wait for synchronous replication and terminating connection due to administrator command\nDETAIL:  The transaction has already committed locally, but might not have been replicated to the standby.\ncreatedb: database creation failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly\n\tThis probably means the server terminated abnormally\n\tbefore or while processing the request.", "stderr_lines": ["WARNING:  canceling the wait for synchronous replication and terminating connection due to administrator command", "DETAIL:  The transaction has already committed locally, but might not have been replicated to the standby.", "createdb: database creation failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly", "\tThis probably means the server terminated abnormally", "\tbefore or while processing the request."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Sometimes run the command on the server directly will also got pending.

If restart PostgreSQL service will fix the issue. What's the problem?

---

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_locks;
   locktype    | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |       mode       | granted | fastpath
---------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------+------------------+---------+----------
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 7/10       |               |         |       |          | 7/10               | 30451 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 6/3        |               |         |       |          | 6/3                | 30290 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 relation      |    13808 |    11577 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 3/3                | 29004 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 3/3        |               |         |       |          | 3/3                | 29004 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 relation      |        0 |     2676 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/10               | 30451 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |           569 |         |       |          | 7/10               | 30451 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 relation      |        0 |     1260 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/10               | 30451 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |           568 |         |       |          | 7/10               | 30451 | ShareLock        | f       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |           568 |         |       |          | 6/3                | 30290 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 relation      |        0 |     2677 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/10               | 30451 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 relation      |        0 |     1260 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 6/3                | 30290 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
(11 rows)
```

Comment: nowadays (maybe that was not even possible in 2020) you'd use the [community.postgresql.postgresql_db](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_db_module.html#ansible-collections-community-postgresql-postgresql-db-module) module to do this with ansible I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only interesting lock that the conflicting transaction 568 holds is a `ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock on `pg_authid`, so there must be a row locking conflict.

That proves that it is **not** `createdb` that hangs, but `createuser` or the SQL statement `CREATE/ALTER/DROP ROLE`.

It must be that transaction 568 is currently adding, or modifying a user, and your blocked transaction 569 must be trying to modify the same user concurrently.

**Solution:** make sure that the blocking transaction 568 is closed or the session terminated.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, before ran `createdb`, also ran `createuser` in the previous ansible playbook task. But that one also got hanging. Could you tell me how to close a blocking transaction?

Comment: In the case shown by your `pg_locks` output, that would be `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(30290);`. The number is the backend process ID (`pid`) of the blocking session.